# Svelte store conditional auto subscription

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

#### Reproduction steps:

- go to REPL here: https://svelte.dev/repl/27a2cff81ebb4000970eee32747cc6c2?version=3.20.1
- open the console
- uncomment line 27 (`$: canSubscribe && $store`)

**Expected**:

I thought that the `$store` can subscribe (with the `$:`) **only** if `canSubscribe` is true.

The question is: **Why `$store` subscribe if `canSubscribe` is false?**

Am I wrong?

Comment: Don't use links with code, provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I wrong?

Yes. Don't blame yourself though, your expectation seems only logical to me. But that's not the way it works.

As a general rule, if there is a `$` prefixed variable somewhere in your component's code, then **it must be a store**, and it will be subscribed right away on component creation, and unsubscribed when the component is destroyed.

A minor exception to this rule was introduced quite recently though (with [this PR](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/4304)). I'll let you follow the trail down the rabbit hole if you want to know the whole discussion. The crux of it is that, now, a store subscription must be a store ***or* nullish** (that is, `null` or `undefined` -- see [this comment](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4520#issuecomment-595941206)).

This means it is now possible to hack your way into the behavior you expected, if needed. We're coming back to this.

> Why $store subscribe if canSubscribe is false?

Because stores are subscribed right away. My understanding, from the discussion in the issues linked above, is that it is for performance (byte size) and sanity (fail fast and visibly if someone tries to subscribe to something that is not a store). Makes sense to me.

Now, back to the question you didn't ask: *how* to subscribe only when/if needed? Put the store in the auto subscribed variable only when needed, and keep it nullish otherwise.

Don't do:

```js
$: started && $store
```

Do this instead:

```js
$: proxyStore = started ? store : null
$: console.log($proxyStore)
```

Full example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0a24500baa5849e4a1769f527a2c9b92?version=3.20.1)):

```html
<script>
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

    const state1 = { subscribed: 0, unsubscribed: 0 }

    const store1 = writable(42, () => {
        state1.subscribed++
        return () => {
            state1.unsubscribed++
        }
    })

    const state2 = { subscribed: 0, unsubscribed: 0 }

    const store2 = writable(43, () => {
        state2.subscribed++
        return () => {
            state2.unsubscribed++
        }
    })

    let started = false

    $: started && $store1

    $: targetStore = started ? store2 : null

    $: $targetStore
</script>

<pre>
started = {started}
store1 = {$store1} {JSON.stringify(state1)}
store2 = {$targetStore} {JSON.stringify(state2)}
</pre>

<button on:click={() => {started = !started}}>
    {started ? 'Start' : 'Stop'}
</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Svelte walks the AST at **compile time** to determine auto-subscriptions.

It sets up a subscription even when the code accessing the store is unreachable.

**For example:**

```html
import {foo} from './stores'

let condition = false

if (condition) { $foo }
```

Even though `$foo` is technically unreachable, that won't be known until runtime.

**Alternative**: You can always use a manual subscription to work around this. Example:

```js
import {onDestroy} from 'svelte'
import {myStore} from './stores.js'

// subscribe when component is created
const unsubscribe = myStore.subscribe(value => {
  // this is called anytime the value of myStore changes
})

// make sure to unsubscribe when component is unmounted
onDestroy(unsubscribe)
```

Comment: @FredHors I've updated my answer to include an example of manual subscription.
You can find more details here:  https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions

Answer (score 3):

In the reactive statement `$: canSubscribe && $store` you have an expression to be evaluated. Since it is reactive, Svelte has to determine when to re-evaluate this expression and this will happen on two occassions: when `canSubscribe` changes, or when `$store` changes. So it will have to make a *subscribtion* to both of those values, hence you see that you immediately get a subscriber in your code.

Note that we often do `canDoSomething && canDoSomething()` in JavaScript but that is not 100% the same as doing `if (canDoSomething) { canDoSomething()}` it just has, in most cases, the same effect.

Comment: Ok. But also if I use `if (canSubscribe) { $store }` it subscribes also if `canSubscribe` is false. This is my problem now.

Comment: yes, the reactiveness is triggered whenever anything in the block changed. I am not sure what you're trying to achieve in the first place, my answer is just pointing out why it doesn't work as you expect.